# Best strategy for public sharing for the pages which are protected by passportjs

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am beginner with the dev overall. I am using passportjs authentication (local and Google strategies) with Mongostore for my nodejs project. Basically, users create a simple page in their private account which only they can view and edit. I need to give them an option to be able to make this page viewable by public. (ie : Let everyone see this page who has the link)

I searched for it, and seems like conditional use of ensureAuth middleware seems not possible. My best thought is :

1. to check if user is authenticated or not via the ensureAuth middleware (this is what i have atm)
2. If not authenticated, check if this page available for public
3. If it is available for public, send only not sensitive data back.

To implement this with all routes didn't seem practical to me.

I am using ensureAuth middleware to protect my routes like so :

```
router.post('/', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const newBlend = new Blend({ ...req.body, user: req.user[0]._id })

    try {
        await newBlend.save()
        res.send(newBlend)
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            return res.status(400).send(
                Object.values(err.errors)
                    .map((val) => val.message)
                    .toString()
            )
        }
        res.status(400).send(err.message)
    }
})
```

My question is : **What is the best strategy for this scenario described above? How can i achieve that with minimum refactoring?**

As i am sort of at the beginning of the project, I would like to structure everything for this scenario before it is too late.

Thank you for your help in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am getting this right but I think you mean you want to avoid repetition with each route (having `ensureAuth` in the parameters with each route)?

You could do `router.use(ensureAuth);` and all other middleware you want to include with every request.